# Nothing is appearing when i switch JPanels

Tags: java, jpanel

Im rather new at Java, I am have created a home page and a few buttons, When i click one of the buttons it sets the homepage panel visibility to false, opens a new class and sets that classes Jpanel to visible.

```
homePanel.setVisible(false);
Goodsin Barcode = new Goodsin();
Goodsin.setVisible(true);
```

However once it opens the new class "Goodsin" it wont show any of the Buttons or  TextFileds. I know it is opening the new class as a System.out.println prints to the console but nothing displays in the JFrame and i do not know why.

Here is my code of the new class

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Goodsin {

    public JPanel Goodsin;
    public JTextField item1;
    public String code;
    public JButton btn1;

    public Goodsin() {

        System.out.println("TEST");

        Goodsin = new JPanel();
        item1 = new JTextField(10);
        btn1 = new JButton("Look up Barcode");

        Goodsin.setVisible(true);

        Goodsin.add(item1);
        item1.setSize(80, 30);

        Goodsin.add(btn1);
        btn1.setSize(80, 30);

    }

    public void getString(String code) {
        System.out.println(code);

    }

}
```

Im sure i am not doing something correct with the Jpanel or adding the textfields or button but all the answers i have seen so far havnt worked.

Comment: how could you create an attribute called Goodsin?

Comment: If Goodsin has not been added, then setting its visibility will mean nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add your panels to a JFrame. You can either do this by extending JFrame from the class or simply instantiating one in your constructor. Then you can simply add and remove (or set visible/invisible) as you wish. Be sure to validate your JFrame/JPanel after changing visibility though.

Comment: We have a JFrame in the Main which is still visible when you click to go through to Goodsin Class but it doesnt seem to be adding the Panel form Goodsin Class to the JFrame. It just returns a blank JFrame

Comment: Have you tried doing nameOfJFrame.revalidate() and nameOfJPanel.revalidate()?

Comment: Ok i added a new JFrame to my Goodins Class which when i click the button to go to Goods in it open a New JFrame and display what i need, But how do i get it to display in the JFrame i already have, so a new window doesnt open?

Comment: Simply don't add a new JFrame, use the original one you instantiated. Just add/remove JPanels from this as you wish. Whenever I make GUIs using Java Swing, I always add a 'back panel' that sits on top of the JFrame and then I add/remove everything from this so that I never accidentally touch the JFrame, you could do the same if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

```
    Goodsin = new JPanel();
      item1 = new JTextField(10);
      btn1 = new JButton("Look up Barcode");

       item1.setSize(80, 30);
       Goodsin.add(item1);

       btn1.setSize(80, 30);
      Goodsin.add(btn1);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
      Goodsin.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      frame.add(Goodsin);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the following code :

```
public class Goodsin extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Goodsin ui = new Goodsin();
        JTextField item1 = new JTextField(10);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Look up Barcode");
        JPanel centralPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        centralPanel.add(item1);
        centralPanel.add(btn1);
        item1.setSize(80, 30);
        btn1.setSize(80, 30);
        ui.add(centralPanel);

        ui.pack();
        ui.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Everything is done in the main method in my example, however you still can improve this code and refactor it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

just you have to set Bounds of Goodsin panel or set Size and  add in home page frame